# edit does not founding an id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to do an edit without scarffolding and it is working the problem is that it cannot pick up the id or primary key of a record i am editing. Below is my code from an service repository until my view as i am using repository pattern.

here is my declaration in INTERFACE SERVICE REPOSITORY

```
void Edit(DonataryKind model);
```

here is my code/method in SERVICE REPOSITORY

```
public void Edit(DonataryKind model)
        {
            _donataryKindyRepository.Update(model);
        }
```

here is my declaration in INTERFACE BUSINESS LOGIC

```
void Edit(DonataryKindView model);
```

here is my code/method in BUSINESS LOGIC

```
 public void Edit(DonataryKindView model)
        {
            using (var donRepo = new DonataryKindRepository())
            {
                var objDon = donRepo.GetById(model.KindID);


                if (objDon != null)
                {
                    objDon.KindName = model.KindName;
                    donRepo.Edit(objDon);
                    donRepo.Save();
                }
            }
        }
```

My code of edit in my CONTROLLER

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var objdonk= new DonataryKindLogic().GetById(id);
            return View(objdonk);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, DonataryKindView model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    var objDonK = new DonataryKindLogic();
                    objDonK.Edit(model);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error! " + e.Message);
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

My code VIEW of edit

```
@model Sunday.Model.DonataryKindView

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DonataryKindView</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.KindID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KindName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KindName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KindName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Don`t you have your id in your model ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don`t you just pick it from the model in the edit method ?

```
model.KindID
```